# Howto pythonic way to integrate pynba and Flask?

Tags: python, flask, decorator, wsgi

after 
pip install flask
pip install pynba

i try following code

```
    import flask
    import pynba.wsgi

    class FlaskWithPynba(flask.Flask):
        @pynba.wsgi.monitor(('localhost', 30002))
        def wsgi_app(self, environ, start_response):
            super(FlaskWithPynba, self).wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    app = FlaskWithPynba('myapp')
```

but have some errors when call app.run()

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/coffee/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", 
    line 1836, in __call__
        return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
      File "pynba/wsgi/middleware.pyx", line 63, 
    in pynba.wsgi.middleware.PynbaMiddleware.__call__ (pynba/wsgi/middleware.c:1554)
      File "pynba/wsgi/middleware.pyx", line 64, 
    in pynba.wsgi.middleware.PynbaMiddleware.__call__ (pynba/wsgi/middleware.c:1510)
    TypeError: wsgi_app() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like pynba decorator is only designed to work on a normal function and not a method of a class.

You would need to do something like:

```
myapp = Flask()

@pynba.wsgi.monitor(('localhost', 30002))
def app(environ, start_response):
    return myapp(environ, start_response)
```

Writing a single decorator implementation that can work on both functions and methods of a class is non trivial. They should perhaps look at `wrapt` decorator library and use it to do it properly.

FWIW. If their middleware wrapper is:

- https://github.com/johnnoone/pynba/blob/master/pynba/wsgi/middleware.py#L39

then it also doesn't the job properly anyway. When a WSGI application is a generator all that will time is how long Python took to create the generator object. It will not time how long the WSGI application code took to run. Even on a normal function for the WSGI application, it will not time how long it took for the WSGI server to send the response and then subsequently call the `close()` of any iterable returned. It is therefore not at accurate representation of how long the WSGI application as a whole took.